# Can you disable the Recents button on the navigation bar for Android 13?

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, recents-screen, navigation-bar, android-13

On my Galaxy S22 phone (running Android 13), when I tap the Recents button on the navigation bar, it shows "# active in background" at the top of the screen if I have # apps active in the background (assuming # > 0).  If I then click on "# active in background", a window will pop up labeled "Check background activity", and I am able to force stop any of my apps that are running in the background from that screen.  I use an "app blocker" app called AppLock Fingerprint (from the Google Play store, developer SpSoft), and I can easily force stop AppLock Fingerprint by doing this, which defeats the purpose of having it.  Is there any way to disable the "# active in background" button, the "Check background activity" window, or the Recents button on the navigation bar itself?